# Can I link an external lib into a header-only visual studio project for use in other solutions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, boost, linker

I've been using Boost's ASIO library to do network and socket communication. Now I'm getting to a point in the development cycle where I'd like to clean things up and make them a little more modular. My first thought was that I would use a separate project for just the network communication part (essentially factoring out the Boost-dependent stuff) and use one visual studio project in two different visual studio solutions. Something like:

```
Client.sln
->  Client.vcxproj
->  Networking.vcxproj

Server.sln
->  Server.vcxproj
->  Networking.vcxproj
```

I tried to do this, but I have the problem that my Networking.vcxproj has turned into a header-only project due to the fact that I'm creating nothing but template classes. What I would ideally like to do is place the references to the boost pre-compiled libs only in the Networking.vcxproj and link against the output of Networking.vcxproj. However, if I understand correctly, there's nothing to link against since my Networking.vcxproj has no .cpp files.

Is there any way to link against my Networking project and the boost ASIO libs without specifying all the additional library dependencies in all the projects? i.e. Is there any way to somehow create the project settings so that I don't have to duplicate the boost library dependencies every time I create a new application which uses the Networking.vcxproj project?

Answer (score 1):

Try to put

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")
```

in one of your networking header files. This should force any project that include that header to link against the specified library (with name "libname").

See
[pragma comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/7f0aews7.aspx)

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't have any apparent impact at all. Depending on the configuration of Networking.vcxproj I either get a link error LNK1104 complaining that it can't link against Network.lib, or I simply get link errors complaining that it can't find libboost_system-vc110-mt-gd-1_55.lib. Is visual studio just too stupid to look at the dependencies of a dependent project?

Comment: You should put the #pragma instruction not in the networking project, only in others, also you should link against libraries such as boost only in the .exe project and not in .lib projects (in project dependancies). Remember also that the "libname.lib" should contain the path to the lib starting from the .vcxproj directory that is being built (or an absolute path)